# cast.player.api.Host error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/3018

Tags: android, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, castcompanionlibrary

I have an app which plays Live Channels over Chrome Cast. While most of the channels are played successfully on some channels I get

> cast.player.api.Host error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/3018

I've looked around the web and wasn't able to find related documentation. The Media Player Library's [Common Network Errors](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/mpl_error_codes#common-network-errors) enlists several errors but none under **NETWORK** and so I am not sure if this is infact a **SEGMENT_NETWORK** as the error code suggests.

If anyone has any source where the distinction is clear please post it.

Comment: Isn't it just purely network error as what stated in [`ErrorCode`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api#.ErrorCode)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 it is indeed a network error. The thing is I'm not sure if the error code points to **SEGMENT_NETWORK** or not i.e. what if there is a separate **NETWORK** error which explains 3018 differently. The goal is to avoid the error either by doing something at client or the server.